# TSQL Cannot create index on view - the view uses an implicit conversion from string to datetime

Tags: t-sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2, indexed-view

SQL SERVER 2008 r2

I'm trying to Create an Indexed view however I'm getting the following error

> Cannot create index on view '' because the view uses an implicit conversion from string to datetime or smalldatetime. Use an explicit CONVERT with a deterministic style value.

The issue is with an INT column [GPSTime] that records the number of seconds from '1970-01-01 00:00:00' and I'm trying to CONVERT/CAST this is to a DATETIME, eg

```
CAST(DATEADD(SS,[GPSTime],'1970-01-01' ) AS DATETIME)
```

or

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(SS,[GPSTime],'1970-01-01' ),113)
```

or

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(SS,[GPSTime],'1970-01-01' ),113)
```

Each of the three options above gives me the error I mentioned earlier.

Is the way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to make a guess that the issue is actually on the `'1970-01-01'`, try this:

```
Dateadd(ss, gpsTime, convert(datetime, '1970-01-01', 101))
```

Or you could keep the datetime value in another table (as a datetime to avoid convert) or write a deterministic function to return your datetime as such:

```
create function [dbo].[UnixEpoch]
()
returns datetime
with schemabinding
as
begin
    RETURN convert(datetime, '1970-01-01', 101)
end

go

select objectproperty(object_id('[dbo].[UnixEpoch]'), 'IsDeterministic')

SELECT dbo.unixEpoch()
```

EDIT:

note the datetime style applied to the `convert(datetime, '1970-01-01', 101)`

according to documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx :

> Source or target type is datetime or smalldatetime, the other source
>   or target type is a character string, and a nondeterministic style is
>   specified. To be deterministic, the style parameter must be a
>   constant. Additionally, styles less than or equal to 100 are
>   nondeterministic, except for styles 20 and 21. Styles greater than 100
>   are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113.

Comment: Thanks but with that change I'm getting "The view contains a convert that is imprecise or non-deterministic"

Comment: Changing that to `code` DATEADD(ss, GPSTime , CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 113)) still doesn't work

Comment: what about keeping the value as a datetime in a separate table that way you don't have to keep doing a convert per row?  or writing a deterministic function that returns that datetime?

Comment: a deterministic function that returns that datetime is good idea, Thanks

Comment: updated my answer, note that the first code snip of convert datetime i modified slightly, you need to provide a datetime style in the convert.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error and fixed it by not only using convert:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, firstdate, 102) AS firstdate
```

On the SELECT clause, but also in the WHERE clause as:

```
WHERE  firstdate >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'20150101',102)
```

I hope this solution helps!